# select in mysql joining two tables with two instance of second table column

Tags: mysql, select, join

Sorry I really can't construct a good title, but let me elaborate it. :(

I have table `report` and table `user_account`.

`report` table have columns:

```
user_id | reported_user_id | date
```

---

`user_account` table have columns:

```
user_id | name | email
```

---

I need to get the name of users who reported and name of the user who was reported in one column.

It's like :

```
user_id | name | reported_user_id | name | email | date
```

---

I've tried left join, but I only have this:

```
user_id | reported_user_id | name | email
```

This is my statement:

```
select user_account.name, user_account.email, report.*
from report
left join user_account where user_account.user_id = report.reported_user_id;
```

Please enlighten my mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select reporter.name as reporter_name, reported.name as reported_name
from report
left join user_account reporter on report.user_id = reporter.user_id
left join user_account reported on report.reported_user_id = reported.user_id
```